# "Failed to get the task for process -1"

Tags: ios15

am new to working with iOS, so apologies for what may be a simple question. I have an iOS app that recently stopped working with upgrade to iOS 15. I loaded my previous xcode project into the latest version of Xcode and tried loading again on my iPhone. I'm getting an error stating: "Could not launch "my app name"" "failed to get the process for task -1". In details it provides this additional information. Appreciate any thoughts or input!

```
{
DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "failed to get the task for process -1";
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
"device_model" = "iPhone11,2";
"device_osBuild" = "15.0 (19A346)";
"device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
"launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
"launchSession_state" = 1;
"launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
"operation_duration_ms" = 5872;
"operation_errorCode" = 3;
"operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
"operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
"operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
"param_consoleMode" = 0;
"param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
"param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 0;
"param_debugger_type" = 5;
"param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
"param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
"param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
"param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
"param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
"param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
"param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
"param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
"param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 1;
"param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
"param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 0;
"param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
"param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
"param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
"param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
"param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
"param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
"param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
"param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
"param_install_style" = 0;
"param_launcher_UID" = 2;
"param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
"param_launcher_kind" = 0;
"param_launcher_style" = 0;
"param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
"param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
"param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
"param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5";
"param_runnable_type" = 2;
"param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
"param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
"param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
"sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.0";
"sdk_osVersion" = "15.0";
"sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.4 (Build 20F71)
```

Xcode 13.0 (19234) (Build 13A233)
Timestamp: 2021-09-27T11:54:55-07:00